# improving a select * from statement on sql

Tags: sql, sql-execution-plan

How a to increase the perfomance of a SQL Statement (select * from table where param1=123,param2=345 ) .Suppose a table having more than 500,000 rows of data.

Its a DBF to SQL migration application. All data are migrated to SQL now . while Connecting to new SQL DB its taking more time in first time page load and on the second time page load it is less time

FYI : there is no join between tables , thats why using select * from commands and its a string query executing from VFP. Only Database is changed from DBF to SQL Server 2016.

Things I have done so far: 
1. Added  non clustered index columns based on the where clause param 
2. checked the execution plan.

Comment: This is really a very broad and generic question, and impossible to give you an objective answer. You've provided no schema. You've provided no data. You've only hinted at a generic query (`select *`) and said that it's the only thing you can do (and I can't imagine why you'd have such a restriction).  But also: we don't know what your performance issue is. And lastly: we don't even know what *database* you're using. Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Will you be more specific with your question?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What's a _lakh_?

Comment: Execute `select * from Hugetable`  and go for lunch to receive a relieving letter from the company. There are lot of considerations to be added in your question

Comment: Hi guys this not as  easy as you think , Its an old vfp application migrating to SQL db  and they are used select * from tablename statement for opening a table data.We cant change anything on that statement, But we can set non clustered indexes on columns. Some tables having 500,000 rows . taking 30 to 35 seconds first time page load and second time its loading in 8 to 12 seconds . what I want to know is how we can improve the time in the first time page load ?

Comment: checking the plan guide and SQL cache now .. Am I in a correct path or not ?

Comment: whether plan guide help to improve the perfomance ?  it is loading much faster in second time why ?

Comment: I am passing only  two parameters along with select * from statement example : select * form tablename where param1=11, param2=222

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (every relational databases is a "SQL database") But if you need to retrieve all rows from a table no index or other structural option will help. The performance is limited by your hardware. Depending on the DBMS product this could be improved by exploiting parallel query capabilities.

Comment: Your actual problem is the first time load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've added and index on (param1,param2,id) and the execution plan is using the index there's not much more you can do. If select * is not using the index then add an ORDER BY.

The first time performance is taking the overhead of connecting to the database. Are you using connection pooling? Is this a batch job?

How long is it taking and how long do you expect it to take?

Comment: I need to load 200,000 rows in 4 seconds !. Its taking 30 to 40 second now . is it possible?

Comment: load where? What are you doing with 200K rows?

Comment: loading all data at first  time and filtering it through form controls

Comment: I suggest evaluating the response time of filtering at the database. The reduce (network?) overhead of returning 100s of thousands of rows is worth investigating. *NO* one is going to page through 200K don't underestimate database caching either,

Comment: 167000 rows returning in 10 seconds.. for select * statement. is it a fair time for this much rows ?

Comment: Sure, depending on what you're doing with them. Have you tried filtering at the server as I recommended?

Comment: This 167000 is coming after filtering :) .but still the customer is not satisfied . :D